# How can i use zf tool with git bash

Tags: git, zend-framework, git-bash, zend-tool

I try to attach zf tool into git bash, but this bunch doesn't work

In command line all works fine (i use win7)

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a path issue.  Try `env|grep PATH` in bash to see what bash sees.  Add paths as needed.  You can also try running with giving full path in command line or alternatively, adding extension to the filename (i.e. `zftool.php` instead of `zftool`).